# PHP doesn't recognize mkdir

Tags: php

I'm trying to execute a `mkdir` from my PHP and am getting the error:

> Warning: mkdir() [function.mkdir]: No such file or directory in /home3/mysite/public_html/register.php on line 220

The offending line is:

```
mkdir($filePath, 0777);
```

Does anyone know what's going on?  Shouldn't `mkdir` be in every PHP installation?

Thanks

Comment: You've misunderstood the error. The function is fine. Your path is not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`mkdir()` is in your PHP installation and is working; the error actually shows that you're trying to create a directory inside a directory that doesn't exist.

You may need to pass `true` as the third parameter to make it work recursively, i.e. `mkdir($path, 0777, true)`

Comment: Yes, I realized the error as soon as I saw Danny's comment. The first time you see this error, though, it's not clear.  It says "[function.mkdir]: No such file or directory" which suggests mkdir isn't being found.  I'm curious.  Is everyone who visits this question now and thinks it was stupid going to down vote it for the next year? I think the forum should require a user to make a comment before they can down vote anything. I don't see how this "drive-by down voting" is constructive.

Answer (score 3):

This means that the folder you are trying to create the new folder in, does not exist.

For instance, `mkdir("non/existant/path/newdir")` will fail.

You need to pass the optional `recursive` parameter to `mkdir()`.

Comment: `mkdir($filePath, 0777, true);`